# sending emails sometimes gets UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type 

Tags: java, apache

I have a Java email service which is running on Windows as service with Apache deamon. The service is facing some issue while sending emails.

> javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed;
>    boundary="----=_Part_2_30390274.1303241582331

Meanwhile I tried to run on different machine and problem is occurring only on some machines.

When I am simply running the stand-alone Java program, it's able to send email. When I run it from "Services panel" then it's throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the there was JDK update to 1.6 after which the setup stopped working.
I have re-installed the JDK1.5 and things are working again. But not sure why update interfared with email functionality.